# Unable to remove some menus with unset

Tags: wordpress, menu, user-roles

I have a custom user role that needs access to only certain post types, and I'm trying to hide other menus from them with this:

```
function remove_menus () {

    global $current_user;
    if ($current_user->wp_capabilities['my_custom_capability']){

        global $menu;
        $restricted = array(
        __('Supporters'),
        __('Posts'),
        __('Press Release'),
        __('Consumer Care'),
        __('Tools')
        );
        end ($menu);
        while (prev($menu)){
            $value = explode(' ',$menu[key($menu)][0]);
            if(in_array($value[0] != NULL?$value[0]:"" , $restricted)){unset($menu[key($menu)]);}
        }
    }
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_menus');
```

This works for Supporters (which is another custom post type), Posts, and Tools, but not for Consumer Care or Press Release. I've tried all variations I can think of in the array:

```
__('Consumer_Care'),
__('Consumer-Care'),
__('consumer care'),
__('consumer-care'),
__('consumer_care')
```

None of them do the job. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a [high priority](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API#Hook_to_WordPress) to the action call. Without one, it'll fire at default `10` and many plugins run after that, so your `unset` doesn't get them.

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menus', 999 );
```